# sequelize (postgres) как во вложенной модели указать сойство родительской модели

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

```js
  return db.Project.findAll( {
    include: {
      model: db.Employee,

      include: [
        {
          model: db.Worklog,
          where: {
              created: { $gte: worklogAfter, $lte: worklogBefore },
              projectId: ----- должно быть равным Project id
            }
        },
        {
          model: db.Salary,
        }
      ]
    }
  } );
```

Comment: какую базу используете?

Comment: @Николай Парахневич postgres

Comment: `Op.col` пробовали использовать как `projectId: { [Op.col]: 'db.Project.id' }` ?

Comment: @Николай Парахневич       Да пробовала. Выскакивает ошибка   таблица "db->Project" отсутствует в предложении FROM